# Custom Customizer setting only saving value of 0

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm trying to build a new custom "media" style customizer field (it lets users select a video from the media library OR paste in a url) and everything works except saving the new value.

My customizer settings are:

```
$wp_customize->register_control_type( 'WP3432_Video_Control' );
$wp_customize->add_setting('feed_video_setting', array(
    'default' => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'absint'
));

$wp_customize->add_control(new WP3432_Video_Control( $wp_customize,
'feed_video_control', array(
    'label'   => 'Hero Video',
    'section' => 'feed_settings_section',
    'settings' => 'feed_video_setting',
)));
```

I am setting the setting customizer link manually to_json method:

```
public function to_json() {
    parent::to_json();
    ...
    $this->json['control_name'] = $this->id;
    $this->json['setting_name'] = $this->setting->id;
    ...
}
```

and setting that attribute manually in the content_template method:

```
public function content_template() {
        ?>
    ...
    <span class="use-url"> - or use URL -</span>
    <input class="js--video-url"
        id="{{ data.control_name }}"
        name="{{ data.control_name }}"
        data-customize-setting-link = "{{ data.setting_name }}"
        type="url" 
        value="{{ data.value }}"
    >
    ...
    <?php
}
```

This produces the following markup in the customizer form:

```
<input class="js--video-url" id="archive_video_control" name="archive_video_control" data-customize-setting-link="archive_video_setting" type="url" value="">
```

But when I examine the contents of get_theme_mods() I see:

```
 [archive_video_setting] => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a `url` field in the control but the underlying setting has an `absint` sanitize callback. When you pass a URL string into `absint` you get `0`. So what you should do is check to see if the value is numeric, and then call `absint`; otherwise if it is a string then it should be passed through `esc_url_raw` to sanitize. Here's an example that also includes validation:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'feed_video_setting', array(
    'default' => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => function( $value ) {
        if ( is_numeric( $value ) ) {
            $value = intval( $value );
            if ( $value < 0 ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'invalid_attachment_id', __( 'Invalid attachment ID', 'myplugin' ) );
            }
        } elseif ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = esc_url_raw( $value );
            if ( empty( $value ) ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'invalid_video_url', __( 'Invalid URL', 'myplugin' ) );
            }
        }
        return $value;
    },
) );
```

Please refer also to the external video header control in core for how it is done there:

- https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4.8.0/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L3985-L3990
- https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4.8.0/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L4409-L4419

Comment: oh that was some pretty careless and shameful copy pasta on my part, I think I grabbed that from the built in media field.  Thanks for catching that.